# Error Wrapping ZMQ C++ in a class file

Tags: c++, pointers, zeromq

I wrote a small class to wrap the C++ ZMQ bindings with a class file, but I'm seeing the below error when I try to call the send_message method:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of zmq::error_t: Socket Operation on non-socket`

Effectively, I'm trying to store the socket in a pointer within the class, and then store a pointer to the class in the main file.  Where is the chain being broken?

Here's the relevant code from the class file:

zmq_client.cpp

```
class ZMQClient
{
zmq::socket_t *internal_socket;
public:
    ZMQClient (std::string conn);
    ~ZMQClient () {delete internal_socket;}
    void send_msg (const char * msg);
};
```

zmq_client.cpp

```
ZMQClient::ZMQClient (std::string conn)
{
    //Set the internal socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    internal_socket=&socket;
    internal_socket->connect (conn);
}

void ZMQClient::send_msg (const char * msg)
{
//Convert the character array to zmq::message_t
...
internal_socket->send (request);
}
```

Here's the relevant code in the main.cpp file:

```
#include "src/zmq_client.h"
ZMQClient *zmqo;

void func(const char * msg)
{
zmqo->send_msg(msg);
}

int main()
{
//Set up the outbound ZMQ Client
ZMQClient zout (OMQ_OBConnStr);
zmqo = &zout;
...
func(msg);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
internal_socket=&socket;
```

You are storing the address of a temporary variable.  You should be simply storing the socket by value in your class, along with its context:

```
class ZMQClient
{
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t internal_socket;
```

Then:

```
ZMQClient::ZMQClient(std::string conn)
    : context(1)
    , socket(context, ZMQ_REQ)
{
    socket.connect(conn);
}
```

Comment: The above changes compile, but result in a segmentation fault when executed

Comment: @AlexBarry: Well then I guess it's time to break out the debugger!  We can't do "programming by mail."

Comment: :) Agreed.  Will get GDB running on the VM tonight and will try to post the answer

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this out?

Comment: @PaulMcElroy: This answer is correct, it was just never accepted.  I don't know if OP ever came back to it.